# How to disable a href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

How to disable a href `link` if there's value in PR row from database? Like my sample table below, if there PR disable the link.

Table

```
item_name | PR     |  < Add >  |

ballpen   | pr100  |    <a>    |
pencil    |        |    <a>    |
Paper     |        |    <a>    |
Clip      |        |    <a>    |
```

Codes,

```
  <?php
    echo '<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>PR</th>
        <th><Add></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
            echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['pr'] . '</td>
            <td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="addpr.php?counts=' . $row["id"] . '"></a></td>
       </tr>';
        }
?>
```

I want to disable ballpen row `<a class="fancybox" href="addpr.php?counts=' . $row["id"] . '"></a>` if there's PR in row

Comment: What do you mean by *disable*?

Comment: <a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
        echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['pr'] . '</td>

        <td align="center">';
if (!empty($row['pr'])){
    echo '<a class="fancybox" href="addpr.php?counts=' . $row["id"] . '"></a>';
}
echo'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Missing a `(` around the condition

Comment: that seems backwards from your description, but what ever works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `href` attribute to `"javascript:;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
...
echo '<td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="'.(($row['pr']!="")?'addpr.php?counts='.$row["id"]:'#'). '"></a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to remove the modal (fancybox) functionality then you can do so by removing the class of the link with jquery or javascript..

example

```
$('a[href="PR100"]').removeClass('fancybox');
```

this checks each link on the page.  if the link has an href attribute that is equal to PR100, we remove the fancybox class which would prevent the popup.

your question is pretty cryptic though.  I'm guessing this is what youre asking..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    echo '<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>PR</th>
        <th><Add></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['app_cn'] != '') {
            $url = $row['pr'] ? 'addpr.php?counts=' . $row['pr'] : '#';
            echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $i++ . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['pr'] . '</td>
            <td align="center"><a class="fancybox" href="{$url}"></a></td>
       </tr>';
        }
?>
```